# Processing the string array elements based on Condition

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have a string array whose four elements contains `:` character.Now i have to get to know the position of these four `:`.I am giving real example of my case string array..

```
01:00:54 186252425 Universal Access Number (U 00:00:04 1 0.60 10:15:20 022403550 bai 00:00:03 1 0.60
```

This is the string array that i have split based on the space.Now i have to find out the position of the elements which contains `:`.After this i have to break this string array into two different array with first two `:` containing elements into one and rest into another.

Also third array element i.e `Universal Access Number (U` need to merge into single string in both the cases of string array.

Actually i have to add this string array into string array containing `01:00:54 186252425 Universal Access Number (U 00:00:04 1 0.60` and `10:15:20 022403550 bai 00:00:03 1 0.60`.The main problem that i am facing is that sometimes in the string array `Universal Access Number (U` comes and sometimes `bai` only so not getting any logic to concatenate and use as universal condition.

Please help me..

Comment: What is the desired result, what have you tried? Also, that is not a `string[]` but a `string`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter This is what i have converted into `string[]` based on the spaces..

Comment: But then you also have splitted `Universal Access Number` into three parts and also the parts in parentheses. What is the real requirement/problem, what is your desired result?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes Actually i have to add this string array into string array containing `01:00:54 186252425 Universal Access Number (U 00:00:04 1 0.60` and `10:15:20 022403550 bai 00:00:03 1 0.60`.The main problem that i am facing is that sometimes in the string array `Universal Access Number (U` comes and sometimes `bai` only so not getting any logic to concatenate and use as universal condition..

Comment: use RegEx for string manipulation of these sorts.

Comment: @TimSchmelter What i was thinking that one element after first occurrence of `:` i can concatenate till the second element and rest of the elements are fair enough..

Comment: @TimSchmelter Sir please tell if my way is correct and if yes how can i achieve this?

Comment: Questions asking for custom-written or sample code are off-topic unless they show that an attempt has already been made, and that there is a coding problem that will be of interest to other readers.

Comment: Questions asking for custom-written or sample code are off-topic unless they show that an attempt has already been made, and that there is a coding problem that will be of interest to other readers.